# $ionicConfig vs $ionicConfigProvider

Tags: ionic-framework

It seems like we can do `$ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');` and `$ionicConfig.views.transition('none');`. What is the difference between `$ionicConfig` and `$ionicConfigProvider`?

Answer (score 2):

$ionicConfigProvider will apply to all the views. $ionicConfig is specific to a view.

The difference is clear when you notice that $ionicConfigProvider is given at the app level and $ionicConfig is injected at the controller level.

Eg:

```
angular.module('Test').config(function($stateProvider, $ionicConfigProvider){});

angular.module('Test').controller(function($ionicConfig){})
```

This allows you to change the behaviour of a specific view as against all the views provided by the $ionicConfigProvider.